# VotingRegressor vs. StackingRegressor

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

Here's one. In what situation would you use one vs. the other. Let me run a hypothetical.

Let's say I'm training a few different Regressors, and I get the final `score` from each regressor's training run. If I wanted to use the VotingRegressor to ensemble each model, I could use those scores as potential `weight` parameters to get a weighted average of each model's prediction right?

So what's the benefit of doing that, vs. using the StackingRegressor to get the final prediction? As I understand it, a final model is used to make its predictions based on each individual model's prediction, so in effect, wouldn't that final StackingRegressor model learn that some predictions are better than others? Almost like it's doing a sort of weight voting of its own?

Short of running both examples and seeing the differences in predictions, wondering if anyone else has experience with both of these and could provide some insight as to which might be a better way to go? I don't see a question like this on SO yet. Thanks!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming.  See the Note in the tag wiki for [tag:machine-learning].

Comment: I posted this here as per the scikit learn page here, but yes stack exchange might be better geared for it. Hoping to leave it open here so I don’t have to repost elsewhere and duplicate the request. 

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/support.html